# ElasticSearch search for special characters with pattern analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, query-analyzer

I'm currently using a custom analyzer with the tokenizer set to be the pattern `(\W|_)+` So so each term is only letters and split on any non letter. As an example I have a document with the contents `[dbo].[Material_Get]` and another with `dbo.Another_Material_Get`. I want to be able to search for "Material_Get" and have a hit on both documents but if I put a search of "[Material_Get]" it still hits on `dbo.Another_Material_Get` even though it doesn't have the brackets in it. Also if I search for "Material Get" (in a quoted search) I shouldn't get any hits since neither of them have that phrase in it.

I could settle for an analyzer/tokenizer that would find whenever there is the input string anywhere in the file even if it has other things next to it. For example searching for "aterial_get" would match in both. Is it possible to do either of my cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have explained what I got is that you want to do partial matches also like searching for "aterial_get".

To satisfy all your requirement, you need to change the mapping of your field to have [ngram token filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html) in the analyzer and without removing the special characters. A sample analyzer can look like

```
{
  "settings":{
    "analysis":{
      "analyzer":{
        "partialmatch":{
          "type":"custom",
          "tokenizer":"keyword",
          "filter":[ "lowercase", "ngram" ] 
        }
      },
      "filter":{
        "ngram":{
          "type":"ngram",
          "min_gram":2,
          "max_gram":15
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And define in your mapping for `your_field` the analyzer "partialmatch" defined above. You can change the values of `min_gram` and `max_gram` as per your needs.

With this mapping you can do a normal term search like below

```
{
    "term": {
        "your_field": "aterial_get"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the max_gram of 15 basically saying that if there was a partial search  longer than 15 it wouldn't work? Also is there an easy way to set that to be the analyzer for all fields?

Comment: How slow of a search will this be for large a large amount of large document?

Comment: max_gram of 15  means tokens will be generated upto max length of 15. so search longer than 15  wouldn't work. You can set the same analyzer to all fields but not recommended. For large texts the index size will increase substantially leading to impact in search performance. But again it depends on how much hardware you have and how many documents you have. After all it is also tokens in the inverted index. Generally ngram/edgengram is used on smaller fields for auto-complete type searches.

Comment: A problem i'm noticing right now is that if i had one document with "Material_Get" and another with just the word "at" and i search for "aterial" i hit on both documents which i don't want.

Comment: if you are using `term search` then you won't get both the documents. If you do a `query_string`  type search and didn't define a search analyzer then  the input will be analyzed same as your field(ngram) hence will match both.

Comment: Ok one last question. I'm wondering if there is a way to index like this: Given "[dbo].[Material_Get]" tokenize into tokens "[", "dbo", "]",  ".", "material_get", "]"...Basically strings of uninterrupted characters 1 token and any single non letter a token?

Comment: Also if I do a quoted search "\"[dbo].[material_get]\"" it doesn't return the result that it should

Comment: For tokenizing the way you want, you can use the pattern tokenizer with pattern something like `((?<=[^a-zA-Z])|(?=[^a-zA-Z]))`.  As for the quoted search , if you were doing a term search it won't work as term search inputs are not analyzed and you don't have documents with "quotes". If you give a complete detail of your use case, may be a better solution may come up.